# Generic rxjava2 database access layer

Tags: java, rx-java2

I just started with java/rxjava2/android dev and managed to get the following working example:

```
    Observable<Object> source3 = Observable.create(emitter-> {
                cursor = app.dbh.getAlllTransactions2();
                emitter.onNext(cursor);
                emitter.onComplete();
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

    source3.subscribe(c -> {
        transactionAdapter = new TransactionCursorAdapter(this.getActivity(), (Cursor)c);
        LSTVW_transactions.setAdapter(transactionAdapter);
    });
```

Now I have 2 questions:

1. how is it that I am forced to use Object as a type. If I use anything else 
   android studio says it expects Object.  Is it because of the lambda expression. I have done tests before and they allowed me to use any type.
2. I would like to make the below in a more generic fashion.  The goal is to have Observable as the result with an arbitrary db function as a parameter which in then generically called.  An older example I have found of this can be found here but I don't see how i could convert it to lambda/rxjava2 style (original link: https://dzone.com/articles/easy-sqlite-android-rxjava)

An example of such setup which I would like to convert:

```
private static <T> Observable<T> makeObservable(final Callable<T> func) {
  return Observable.create(
      new Observable.OnSubscribe<T>() {
          @Override
          public void call(Subscriber<? super T> subscriber) {
            try {
              subscriber.onNext(func.call());
            } catch(Exception ex) {
              Log.e(TAG, "Error reading from the database", ex);
            }
          }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Observable.create((ObservableOnSubscribe<YourType>) e -> { ... }
```

I don't get exactly what do you want to achieve with the second snippet, but I think you can simplify just having this body, for the `makeObservable` method (I just removed the try-catch part):

```
return Observable.create(e -> e.onNext(func.call()));
```

About Rx abuse: I think that it is not a good idea to pass the Cursor as item of a stream. You would probably have a stream of data read from the database, so that your Observer can react properly.

Comment: The first one did the trick. thanks!  I tried it myself, but you really needed the parentheses which would serve as a cast (which I missed). for the second part of the question (not taking into account any examples).  I would like to do something like Observable<Cursor> obs1 = makeObservable(getAllX());   Observable<Cursor> obs2 = makeObservable(getAllY());  etc.   For you comment about cursors and individual elements. I agree,  I'm just trying to understand how everything could fit together. loaders, adapters, ,db, rxjava recyclerviews.... etc etc...

Comment: To be more specific:  I tried the func.call() already. but it is unclear to me how i pass it correctly into there, in order for me to call it like this